# Use Python to match a letter in a string only when followed by a space, period, or nothing, without regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write this code for readability but the last 'for x in measurements' clearly doesn't work.

The following prints ' t' but I don't want it to match on ' test'
I do want it to match on ' t' of 'this is a t' if it were a test case.

Possible without resorting to regex?

```
measurements = ['t', 'tsp', 'T', 'tbl', 'tbs', 'tbsp', 'c']
measurements = ([' ' + x + ' ' for x in measurements] + #space on either side
                [' ' + x + '.' for x in measurements] + #space in front, period in back
                [' ' + x + '' for x in measurements])   #space in front, nothing in back???

string_to_check = 'this is a test'

for measurement in measurements:
    if measurement in string_to_check:
        print(measurement)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it print `test`?

Comment: Can you give few more examples? Like positive matches and negative matches examples?

Comment: Edited for clarity because of "vote to close".

Answer (score 1):

Here you could use `re.search`

```
>>> measurements = ['t', 'tsp', 'T', 'tbl', 'tbs', 'tbsp', 'c']
>>> measurements = ([' ' + x + ' ' for x in measurements] + [' ' + x + '\.' for x in measurements] + [' ' + x + r'\b' for x in measurements])
>>> measurements
[' t ', ' tsp ', ' T ', ' tbl ', ' tbs ', ' tbsp ', ' c ', ' t\\.', ' tsp\\.', ' T\\.', ' tbl\\.', ' tbs\\.', ' tbsp\\.', ' c\\.', ' t\\b', ' tsp\\b', ' T\\b', ' tbl\\b', ' tbs\\b', ' tbsp\\b', ' c\\b']
>>> string_to_check = 'this is a test'
>>> for measurement in measurements:
    if re.search(measurement, string_to_check):
         print(measurement)


>>>
```

I had done two things here.

- `[' ' + x + '\.' for x in measurements]`, escape the dot in-order to match a literal dot, since dot is a special meta character in regex which matches any character.
- `[' ' + x + r'\b' for x in measurements]` add word boundary `\b`, since `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character, it won't pick `spacet` from `<space>test`

Comment: Thanks Avinash.  I was pretty sure it couldn't be done without regex.  Your solution at least gets the job done.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're coded for a different meaning of 'nothing behind it' than you're thinking of.

You've included the string ' t' in your array which is a substring of the string 'this is a test' [namely, it's sitting there at the front of the word test].

If you want 'nothing behind it' to mean 'at the end of the string' then you'll have to check what's at the end of the string instead of using substring search.

Answer (score 0):

measurements
`[' t ', ' tsp ', ' T ', ' tbl ', ' tbs ', ' tbsp ', ' c ', ' t.', ' tsp.', ' T.', ' tbl.', ' tbs.', ' tbsp.', ' c.', ' t', ' tsp', ' T', ' tbl', ' tbs', ' tbsp', ' c']`

You can find ' t' in measurements.So ' t' in your check string "this is a[ t]est".
so, it's right to return ' t'.

if you want to exactly match ' t' not ' txxx', you need to
`[' ' + x + r'\b' for x in measurements]`

Answer (score 0):

A possible non-regex approach is to split `string_to_check` into a list of words. Then `in` will look for a word that matches exactly.

```
measurements = ['t', 'tsp', 'T', 'tbl', 'tbs', 'tbsp', 'c']

string_to_check = 'this is a test'
words_to_check = string_to_check.replace('.', ' ').split()
for measurement in measurements:
    if measurement in words_to_check:
        print(measurement)
```